# How to modify all the queries in the upstream `victoria-metrics-k8s-stack` grafana chart?

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, dashboard, victoriametrics

I would like to modify all the queries of the Kubernetes (K8s) stack components/charts to add a new filter. However, I don't want to modify the upstream chart because copy-pasting and making changes can lead to issues in the future while upgrading to a newer version.

I am trying to modify the chart by adding a new query parameter in the datasources.yaml file, as follows:

```
 datasource.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
{{- if or .Values.vmsingle.enabled  .Values.vmcluster.enabled }}
    - name: VictoriaMetrics
      type: prometheus
      url: {{ include "victoria-metrics-k8s-stack.vmSelectEndpoint" . }}
      access: proxy
      isDefault: true
      jsonData:
        query_params:
          product_line: "customer"
```

However, this approach does not seem to work, as it is not adding any query parameters to the original queries triggered by the default dashboard. What is the best way to modify upstream charts, and how can I fix this issue?

Link to upstream charts: https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/victoria-metrics-k8s-stack/templates/grafana/dashboards

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `query_params` is the right name?
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/ doesn't mention it. Instead, it has `Custom query parameters` field.